# Why isn't my data plotting to my pcolor plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to feed my csv data to a pcolor or pcolormesh plot and for some reason it isn't plotting. I don't get any errors, so I am not sure why it wouldn't be plotting. The Xaxis, Yaxis, and color bar scale all appear correct. My 'Intensity' data set is values between 0 and 1. I am new to python so any guidance will be extremely helpful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('mycsv3.csv')
a=df['X'].values
b=df['Y'].values
c=df['Intensity'].values
cb=plt.pcolor([a],[b],[c],cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.title('Pupil Image')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I tried to reshape my Intensity data to X and Y by adding an extra line:
c =df['Intensity'].values.reshape(a,b)
but got a "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

[image]
[image]

Comment: To get intensities, you should choose a different colormap, as `jet` has [a very intense yellow at the wrong spot](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: You probably need `plt.pcolor(a.reshape(M,N),b.reshape(M,N),c.reshape(M,N))` with `M` and `N` the correct dimensions of the grid. Supposing that the data come from a regular grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked about working with data that has a similar structure for a similar goal earlier today, I would suggest that you could follow the same method.

Edit: I have changed the solution a bit, I created a small table of data for demonstration as

```
-1 -1 .2
-1  0 .5
-1  1 .9
-1  2 .7
0  -1  0
0   0 .8
0   1 .1
0   2 .9
1  -1 .5
1   0 .4
1   1 .6
1   2 .7
```

### Solution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

header = ['X', 'Y', 'Intensity']
df_demo = pd.read_csv('democsv.csv')
df_demo.columns = header

df_pivot = df_demo.pivot(columns='X', index = 'Y', values='Intensity')
plt.imshow(df_pivot, extent =[-1, 1, -1, 2], origin = 'lower', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
```

### Output

[image: Output]

A weakness of my solution is that it also changes to plotting via imshow. This assumes that the sampling rate is equal. Also, note that I flipped the origin to match to more closely match this data as an example of how to do that.